# Find text in string Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get a value from text line in Excel
for example

```
Cell A = abcederfsdfdeikdfKEY=testOnFly&gameFound
```

I would like to return the Key value which is `"testOnFly"`

How can i do this using a simple function or VBA?

Comment: What have you tried ? Edit: Oh and you don't even need VBA for this, unless you are required to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it;

```
=(MID(A1,FIND(E1,A1)+LEN(E1),(FIND(F1,A1)-FIND(E1,A1)-LEN(E1))))
```

Comment: Glad you found it. Please note that in the enghlish version, commas `,` are used as separators in formulas. I've edited your answer this way.

Comment: I didn't know that. Let then say I've changed for the most widespread version (english and commas) :D